# IE11 border style issue when sides are different colors

Tags: css, border, internet-explorer-11

I've encountered an issue with border style and IE11 being different than the way firefox and chrome display it.

In IE11, on the green and blue colored elements, there is a bevel visible on the bottom right corner when the bottom-boarder and right-boarder are different colors.

That beveling is not visible in chrome and firefox. I can't seem to find anything that will eliminate that in IE11. Any ideas?

Example code:
https://jsfiddle.net/s4pecmv5/3/

```css
body{
background-color:white;
}
.container{
  display:table;
  width:auto;
  border-radius:3px;
}
.container,table,table tr{
border: 3px solid lightgray;
}
table{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
table,table tr{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
table td {
border:none;
padding:15px;
text-align:center;
}
table thead {
background-color:lightgray;
}
table thead td {
font-weight:bold;
color:darkgray;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

table td:nth-child(1){
  text-align:left;
}

table tbody td:nth-child(2),
table tbody td:nth-child(3){
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
}
table tbody td:nth-child(2){
border-top:3px solid green;
border-bottom:3px solid green;
border-right:3px solid white;
background-color:lightgreen;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px green;
}

table tbody td:nth-child(3){
border-top:3px solid blue;
border-bottom:3px solid blue;
background-color:lightblue;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px blue;
}

table tbody tr:first-child td {
border-top:3px solid lightgray;
}

table tbody tr:last-child td {
border-bottom:3px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>afdas sdf sadf</td>
<td>dfhfd</td>
<td>gjklg</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>afdas sdf sadf</td>
<td>dfhfd</td>
<td>gjklg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>afdas sdf sadf</td>
<td>dfhfd</td>
<td>gjklg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>afdas sdf sadf</td>
<td>dfhfd</td>
<td>gjklg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>afdas sdf sadf</td>
<td>dfhfd</td>
<td>gjklg</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Chrome screenshot:

[image]

IE11 screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Try giving `translate3d(0,0,0)` or `translateZ(0)` to the element which shows the border.

Comment: Do you want to understand what's causing the border in IE11 or how to fix it?

Comment: @JonathanChaplin A fix would be ideal. I'm assuming it has something to do with IE's rendering of the box model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "td:nth-child" classes you had a border on the top and bottom of each td.

```
border-top:3px solid green;
border-bottom:3px solid green;
```

You also have a border on the tr:

```
border: 3px solid lightgray;
```

This results in a double border look on the "td" change the following classes:

```
.container, table{
   border: 3px solid lightgray;
}

table tbody td:nth-child(2){
   border-right:3px solid white;
   background-color:lightgreen;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px green;
}

table tbody td:nth-child(3){
   background-color:lightblue;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px blue;
}
```

I tested in Chrome IE11 and Firefox and the bevel border is removed.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want the border. However, you have border:collapse in the table and specify border on "table" and "tr".

Comment: Doubling up on the borders for tr and td seems to have been the problem. I just had to add the top & bottom gray border on the td's for the first column of cells. Thanks!